# Swift make background color flash or blink 2 random colors every time the button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift

This app currently starts out with a black screen and when the button in the middle is pressed it change the background color every time the button is pressed. But I want the app to blink or flash 2 different colors: not just show one color that is not flashing.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemYellow,
        .systemGreen,
        .systemPurple,
        .systemPink,
        .systemRed,
        .systemBlue,
        .systemOrange,
        .black,.gray
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapButton() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1/12, delay:0, options:[ ], animations: {
            self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors.randomElement()
            self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors.randomElement()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors.randomElement()
}, completion: { finished in
   print("another animation! - 1")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors.randomElement()
    }, completion: { finished in
      print("another animation! - 2")
    })
})
```

---

### Edit 1

To make forever use below.

```
func showColor() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors.randomElement()
    }, completion: { finished in
       print("another animation! - 1")
       Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(showColorAgain), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    })
}

@objc func showColorAgain() {
    showColor()
}
```

Now to make your logic until next click, you can handle that inside zshowColorAgain` function.

Comment: that's very close and thank you ! but how can I make it flash 2 colors forever until the button is pressed again

Comment: thank you but it still doesn't work? u want me to delete everything I have and paste what u have right.. sorry very new

Comment: @ArashKalhori : Yes, use the code I have in Edit 1. Previous answer is useless

Comment: @ArashKalhori : Inside didTapButton, call `showColor()`. Rest should work

Comment: it doesn't work it gets stuck in black screen :( I put what u did inside didtapbuttonh and I get errors

Comment: do you mind if you post the whole code ? :/ sorry to bother u

Comment: @ArashKalhori : u have teamviewer?

Comment: trying to download it but my internet is really slow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231233/discussion-between-fahim-parkar-and-arash-kalhori).

Comment: @ArashKalhori : Come in chat

Comment: how do I come in chat? I actually got it to work !!!! thank you sooo much :))))) when I press the button it changes between every color! one last thing do u know hoe I can make only 2 colors flash every time I press button ? and when pressed 2 new colors will flash

Comment: @ArashKalhori : Mark answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: @FahimParkar why timer for animations? And instead of recursion wouldn't `[.repeat, .autoreverse]` be better

Answer (score 0):

```
func blink() {
    let colors: [UIColor] = [color1, color2, color3, color4...]
    runBlink(with: colors)
}

func runBlink(with colors: [UIColor]) {
    guard let color = colors.first else { return }
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        self.backgroundColor = color
    }, completion: { finished in
        if finished {
            var nextColors = colors
            nextColors.removeFirst()
            self.runBlink(with: nextColors)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: please add a bit of code desription